# Objective C-Custom Delegate not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I am trying to get a string from a view controller to another using delegate method.But the delegate method is not getting called.Below is the code

```
@protocol CustomDelegate<NSObject>
  -(void)didDataRecieved;
@end 

@interface CustomController:UIViewController
@property id<CustomDelegate>delegate;
@property(retain,nonatomic)NSString *string;
@end

@implementaion CustomController
-(void)viewDidLoad
  {
    string=@"hello";
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector@selector(didDataRecived)]) {
       [self.delegate didDataRecieved];
    }
  }

-(IBACTION)gotoViewController
 {
   ViewController *view=[self.storyboard instantiateViewController:@"View"]; 
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:view aniamted:YES];
 }
@end

@interface ViewController:UIViewController<CustomDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,retain)CustomController *cust;
@end

@implementation ViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
   self.cust=[[CustomController alloc]init];
   self.cust.delegate=self;
 }

-(void)didDataRecieved
 {
  NSLog(@"data %@",self.cust.string);
 }
@end
```

Can anyone point out where am going wrong...plz help.

edited the code..tried this way too.

```
  if([self.delegate respondsToSelector@selector(didDataRecived)]){
    [self.delegate didDataRecieved];
   }
```

Comment: Are you pushing/presenting your `CustomController` anywhere?

Comment: Are you sure that `viewDidLoad` is being called? How do you know?

Comment: try a breakpoint inside `didDataRecieved`

Comment: @Vijay Yes i am pushing the view controller ie,CustomController to ViewController

Comment: @Arc676 yes viewDidLoad is getting called tried an NSLog inside it and its shows

Comment: @abhi1992 doesn't reach the breakpoint

Comment: Try `nil`-checking `delegate` in your `CustomController`. Unless you're positive there aren't any other instances of it in your app. (Just in case there's actually another `CustomController` somewhere and that's the one calling `viewDidLoad` but without getting a delegate)

Comment: Can you check that your delegate method is responding using this.  `if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDataRecieved)]) { [self.delegate didDataRecieved]; }`

Comment: @Prarthana, you should check the `respondsToSelector` where you are calling your delegate methods. Probably it should be in your `CustomController `

Comment: @Vijay...thanks for the edit. But no hope, control not entering the if condition.can it be something with the view controllers..I am doing a push of the view using the storyboard identifiers!

Comment: @Prarthana Can you try your delegate methods at `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: The control ins not entering the if block means either delegate property is not set or the delegate does not implement the delegate method you want to call. Set the delegate property when you are creating viewController instance and implement the method in delegate class.

Comment: Also, where are you pushing/presenting the controller created via `self.cust=[[CustomController alloc]init];` ?

Comment: @Ad-J edited the code- added the IBaction where the push the view

Comment: You are trying to launch the `ViewController` from `CustomController` and then creating `CustomController` object in `ViewController` and setting its delegate but that object is never pushed, so it of course not work. Your code looks quite messed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you the sample coding.Customize the below code.

Here we have two view controllers.

ViewController
and
SecondViewController

in SecondViewController

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class SecondViewController;
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)secondViewController didEnterText:(NSString *)text;
@end
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign)id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;  
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;//It must connect as outlet connection
- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface SecondViewController ()
@end
@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//Either use NSNotification or Delegate
- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender;
{
          //Use Notification
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"passingDataFromSecondViewToFirstView" object:self.nameTextField.text];
          //OR Custom Delegate
     [self.delegate secondViewController:self didEnterText:self.nameTextField.text];
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

in ViewController

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SecondViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelName; //You must connect the label with outlet connection
- (IBAction)gotoNextView:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   //addObserver here...
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFromPreviousViewControllerNotificationReceived:) name:@"passingDataFromSecondViewToFirstView" object:nil];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

//addObserver Method here....
- (void)textFromPreviousViewControllerNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   // set text to label...
   NSString *string = [notification object];
   self.labelName.text = string;
}
- (IBAction)gotoNextView:(id)sender;
{
   //If you use storyboard
   SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
   //OR  If you use XIB
   SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
   secondViewController.delegate = self;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}

//Calling custom delegate method
- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)secondViewController didEnterText:(NSString *)text
{
   self.labelName.text = text; //Getting the data and assign the data to label here.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
```

For your understanding the code I create a simple passing data from one second view controller to first view controller.

First we navigate the view from first view controller to second view controller.

After that we send the data from second view controller to first view controller.

**NOTE : You can either use NSNotification or Custom Delegate method for sending data from One View Controller to Other View Controller**

If you use NSNotification, you need to set the **postNotificationName** for getting data  in button action method.

Next you need to write **addObserver** in (sending data to your required View Controller) ViewController and call the addObserver method in same View Controller.

If you use custom delegate,
Usually we go with **Custom Protocol Delegate** and also we need to **Assign** the delegate here.

Very importantly we have to set the **Custom Delegate Method** in the **Second View Controller**.Because where we send the data to first view controller once we click the done button in second view controller.

Finally we must call the **Custom Delegate Method** in **First View Controller**, where we get the data and assign that data to label.Now you can see the passed data using custom delegate.

Likewise you can send the data to other view controller using **Custom Delegate Methods**

Answer (score 0):

how you pushing your second controller? i cant see.
but your code working for me.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ViewController1 *vc = [ViewController1 new];
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)didDataRecieved
{
    NSLog(@"recieved");
}

@end
```

Comment: am using a push - ViewController *view=[self.storyboard instantiateViewController:@"View"]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:view aniamted:YES];

Comment: self.cust=[[CustomController alloc]init];  and  ViewController *view=[self.storyboard instantiateViewController:@"View"];  are different instances! when you presenting controller, you not assign delegate reference. before presenting.  use view.delegate = self